# Python not recognising libraries on Windows machine

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have been having a lot of trouble on my work Windows machine. I cannot get any libraries to work on my python. I use Thonny application for my python scripting.

I have tried setting environmental path to my current directory of python. On my PC its :
C:\Users\petrikas.lu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts

Most tutorials say that it should be on C:\Python34\Scripts however thats not the case for my PC.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buWwu.png)

Python directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcxqW.png)

Can someone suggest me what shall I do next? I have tried many things that I have found online but my script wont compile. I am trying to import pandas library

After running a command:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

It does not return any result. Most certainly did not generate a pandas library in my libs python folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting up a [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html) environment (using Anaconda or Miniconda) for your Windows machine. It's much easier to manage different environments which contain different sets of libraries.

Comment: I have done it. It workoud straight out of the box with my pandas libraries. Maybe it came with pandas already preinstalled. How do you install a new python libraries to that environment?

Comment: Normally you can either use pip install [library_name] or conda install [library_name] depending on the type of environment you are in.